# Ouputting a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a currency calculator on a website I am working on. I have it working absolutely fine so that two currencies output correctly depending on which input you are using.

But now I need a line to appear after the calculation has happened which shows the exact exchange rate.

So rather than showing what the user has input, it just shows the value of what 1 GBP is in the target currency. The first result will always be 1 GBP as that is the only base currency being used.

So for example:
1 GBP = X in target currency

(e.g: "1 GBP is equal to 1.24 USD" or 1 GBP is equal to 1.5 EUR)

The original HTML is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var js = document.createElement('script'); js.type = 'text/javascript'; js.async = true;
js.src = 'http://www.floatrates.com/scripts/converter.js';
var sjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];       sjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, sjs);
 })();
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#from").msDropdown();
})
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#to").msDropdown();
})
</script>

<form class="frConverter">
  <div class="field-row">
    <div class="from">
      <label for="from">Sending From:</label>
      <select id="from" value="gbp" name="base_currency" class="select-box">
        <option value="GBP" data-image="http://inaramoneytran.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/monex/assets/img/uk.gif" data-imagecss="flag" selected="">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="base_value" size="10" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="default_base" value="gbp">
    </div>

    <div class="to">
      <label for="to">Sending To:</label>
      <select id="to" value="USD" name="target_currency" class="select-box">
        <option value="USD" data-image="http://inaramoneytran.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/monex/assets/img/us.gif" data-imagecss="flag">United States (Dollar) - USD</option>
        <option value="GBP" data-image="http://inaramoneytran.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/monex/assets/img/uk.gif" data-imagecss="flag">United Kingdom (Pound) - GBP</option>
     </select>            
     <input type="hidden" name="default_target" value="usd">
     <input type="text" name="target_value" size="10" value="">
    </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you include enough code to make the calculator work and include it within a single snippet ?   Use the  toolbar button with an icon and `< >` on it

Comment: Sure I have now edited the code

Comment: code.. where you show the result ?

Comment: Sorry I meant I have now edited the question to include the scripts as requested.

Comment: use the <> snippet so we can see a working example.

Comment: You should try doing it on your own and ask here for help on solving the problems you encounter. Otherwise it looks like you ask other people to do the job for you. And if you get paid for it then it doesn't seem fair.

Comment: I have been trying to do it on my own... For many hours. Hence me asking for help solving it here. As you suggested. Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: Can you update question and clearly show us what the expected result would be??   User enters 1 for USD and selected GBP, then below it you want it to say: `1 USD -> 1.24 GBP` ?  or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have updated the question to try and make it as simple as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work off the change event or focusout event on the inputs (im guessing the floatrates script is somehow hijacking these events) so this is currently firing on any change to `document`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).change(function() {
  getSingleExchange();
});


function getSingleExchange() {
  var fromCurr = $("#from option:selected").val();
  var toCurr = $("#to option:selected").val();
  var from = $('input[name=base_value]').val();
  var to = $('input[name=target_value]').val();

  rate = parseInt(from) / parseInt(to);

  output = fromCurr + " to " + toCurr + "= " + rate.toFixed(2);

  $("#singleExchangeValue").html(output);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.floatrates.com/scripts/converter.js"></script>

<form class="frConverter">
  <div class="field-row">
    <div class="from">
      <label for="from">Sending From:</label>
      <select id="from" value="gbp" name="base_currency" class="select-box">
        <option value="GBP" data-image="http://inaramoneytran.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/monex/assets/img/uk.gif" data-imagecss="flag" selected="">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="base_value" name="base_value" size="10" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="default_base" value="gbp">
    </div>

    <div class="to">
      <label for="to">Sending To:</label>
      <select id="to" value="USD" name="target_currency" class="select-box">
        <option value="USD" data-image="http://inaramoneytran.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/monex/assets/img/us.gif" data-imagecss="flag">United States (Dollar) - USD</option>
        <option value="GBP" data-image="http://inaramoneytran.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/monex/assets/img/uk.gif" data-imagecss="flag">United Kingdom (Pound) - GBP</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="default_target" value="usd">
      <input type="text" name="target_value" size="10" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div id="singleExchangeValue"></div>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you for your help I can certainly use this as a base to edit it to how I would like it. I am very appreciative.